# How to fill text area and click on button using c#?

Tags: c#, button, click, watin

I am having problem with filling text area and click on the button using my c# code... please give me example if you have I dont care if you are using webbrowser or watin or whatever...

```
<textarea class="textarea" placeholder="Say something" style="overflow: hidden;"></textarea>



<div class="comment-submit-container">
<button class="comment-submit" type="submit">Post Comment</button>
<img class="comment-submit-loading" width="16" height="16" src="www.notimportantlink.com" alt="">
</div>
```

this is what I have tried using class..basically help from stackoverflow

```
webBrowser1.DocumentText = "text with classes";
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);

void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

            foreach (HtmlElement txt in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("textarea"))
            {
                if (txt.GetAttribute("ClassName") == "textarea")
                {
                    txt.SetAttribute("value", "adsasdassd");
                   // MessageBox.Show("uneseno");
                }
            }
       foreach (HtmlElement btn in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button"))
            {
                if (btn.GetAttribute("ClassName") == "comment-submit")
                {
                    btn.InvokeMember("Click");
                    MessageBox.Show("kliknuto");
                }
            }


        }
```

As you can see in html code there is no ID or name..

Comment: What is exactly the problem? There is no `<form>` in your HTML code, so the button may just do nothing upon a simulated click. Do you actually see the message box "kliknuto"?

Comment: Yes I can see the boxes, thats why I put them to check how my code is going on. But when I check the website nothing happened, it dont upload to website.

Answer (score 2):

In WatiN you can use `Find.ByClass` or by index to find elements

This will flash the button, not click it, for the proof of concept

```
var ie = new IE();
ie.GoTo(@"[link goes here");
ie.TextField(Find.ByClass("textarea")).TypeText("words go here");
ie.Button(Find.ByClass("comment-submit")).Flash(2);
```

If class *textarea* is not unique, you can return all elements of a type and then refernce by index.  EG: `ie.TextFields[0].TypeText("words go here by index");`

Or combine Find criteria like `ie.TextField(Find.ByClass("textarea") && Find.ByIndex(0)).TypeText("words go here compound find");`

.

**HTML used**

```
<html>
<title>This is the title.</title>
<body>
<textarea class="textarea" placeholder="Say something" style="overflow: hidden;"></textarea>
<div class="comment-submit-container">
<button class="comment-submit" type="submit">Post Comment</button>
<img class="comment-submit-loading" width="16" height="16" src="www.notimportantlink.com" alt="">
</div>
</body>
<html>
```

Tested on Watin 2.1, IE9, Win7 64bit